Disable colors in emacs terminal
How to disable all colours in emacs running in a terminal?
Note that I don't want disabling just a buffer.
I don't want (global-font-lock-mode 0) because that only works on normal buffers, however emacs sometimes asks me questions in the mini-buffer in unreadable blue text, so I want to disable colours altogether. Alternatively a settings which just disables colours for the mini-buffer.

The internet tells me that emacs has --color option, so emacs --color=no.

@larsks thanks.
